# How to render template after POST request using Ajax and jinja

Tags: ajax, flask, jinja2

I am building an app with Flask, Bootstrap, and jinja2 which holds some detail's on my devices (mobile phones).

the main page is a table which each row is representing a device. for each device, i have a "Report" column that contains a link to the report page.

currently, i have the following request from home.js

```
$('.report').click(function () {
   console.log("report clicked");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/showDeviceReports',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{'attack':attack},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            document.write(response.data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

now on my flask server, i am processing the request routes.py

```
 @routes.route('/showDeviceReports', methods=['POST','GET'])
def showDeviceReports():
    attack = request.values.get('attack', None)
    print attack
    if attack:
        collection = mongo.db[attack]

        res = collection.find_one({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44"})
        if res:
            res = collection.find_one({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44", "reports._id": "10.0.1"})
            if res:
                # update array object
                collection.update_one({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44","reports._id":"10.0.1"},
                             {'$set':{"reports.0":reports_dict[attack]}})
            else:
                #add new element to report array
                collection.update_one({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44"},
                                   {'$push':{"reports":reports_dict[attack]}})
            pass
        else:
            # myreports = collection.find_one_and_replace({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:22"}, gold_apple_report, upsert=True)
            schema = {"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44",
                          "name":"iphone",
                          "account":"test@gmail.com",
                          "updated_on":str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')),
                          "reports": [reports_dict[attack]]}
            collection.insert_one(schema)
        # myreports = collection.find_one_and_replace({"_id":"dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:22"}, res,upsert=True)
        # print myreports.inserted_id
        res = collection.find_one({"_id": "dd:dd:ff:dd:gg:44"})
    else:
        res = {}
    return render_template('reports.html', meta=res)
```

and then I would like to load the `reports.html` page
including the `meta` data that I pass to the page.

this is the reports.html:

```
<div class="tree well">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i> {{meta["name"]}}</span>

                    <ul>
                        {% for v in meta["reports"] %}
                        <li>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> {{v["_id"]}} </span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span><i class="fa fa-calendar-o "></i> {{meta["updated_on"]}} </span>
                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    <span ><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Attack flow </span>

                                    <ul >
                                        {% for proc in v["attackProccess"].keys() %}
                                        <li >
                                            <span ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> {{proc}} </span>

                                            <ul id="ul-attack-items">
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="status" id="{{proc}}">{{v["attackProccess"][proc]["status"]}}</span>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-bug status"> issues</span>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                        </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>

                                </li>
                                <li >
                                    <span > <i class="fa fa-database"></i> Data </span>

                                    <ul >
                                        {% for item in v["data"].keys() %}
                                        <li >
                                            <span ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> {{item}} </span>
                                            {% if item == 'chats' %}
                                            <ul>
                                                {% for chat in v["data"][item] %}
                                                 <li>
                                                     <span ><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> {{chat}} </span>
                                                     <ul id="ul-chat-items">
                                                         <li>
                                                             <span class="status" id="{{chat}}" >{{v["data"][item][chat]["status"]}}</span>
                                                         </li>
                                                         <li>
                                                             <span class="fa fa-bug status"> issues</span>
                                                         </li>
                                                     </ul>
                                                 </li>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </ul>
                                            {% else %}
                                            <ul id="ul-data-items">
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="status" id="{{item}}" >{{v["data"][item]["status"]}} </span>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-bug status"> issues</span>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            {% endif %}

                                        </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>

                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

but the problem that I should handle it via the ajax request.
there is some way to integrate `jquery` with `jinja`?

Comment: Do the initial request with GET and ajax call with POST. run separate logic after identifying the request type

Comment: but still how i should render the template? i am using jinja within my template. look at the html code.

Comment: You render your template normally, as in `render_template`. The main difference here is that you will (typically) want to render a snippet and integrate that in your page (e.g. using jQuery or something) when using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Do the initial request with GET and ajax call with POST. run separate logic after identifying the request type"

Thanks to [Priyank Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4822823/priyank-mehta) i solved it using is solution.